# Multiple PDEs in the same DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I have a function of two variables that satisfies two PDEs, say as an example

```
eq1 = D[f[x, y], x] + D[f[x, y], y] == 0
eq2 = D[f[x, y], x] - D[f[x, y], y] == x - y
```

Cleary, the solution is

```
f[x,y]==1/4 (x - y)^2 + C[1]
```

I would like to find this solution by putting eq1 and eq2 in DSolve, that is

```
DSolve[{eq1, eq2}, f, {x, y}]
```

but this doesn't do anything. Instead, I have to solve an equation at the time

```
s1 = DSolve[eq1, f[x, y], {x, y}] // FullSimplify
eq2 /. f -> ((%[[1, 1, 2]] /. {x -> #, y -> #2}) &)
% /. x -> -z + y
s2 = DSolve[%, C[1][z], z] // FullSimplify
s1[[1, 1, 2]] /. (s2[[1]] /. z -> y - x) // FullSimplify
```

which gives

```
1/4 (x - y)^2 + C[2]
```

Why doesn't the first DSolve work?

In practice, I'm dealing with more complicated PDEs, and I have more variables. I can find my solution by solving the differential PDEs one after the other, but it's more annoying, so I was wondering if there's a way of making the DSolve with multiple PDEs work.
I'm on Mathematica 12.0

Comment: It's well-known that `DSolve` is weak. If you search in this site, you'll find a number of answer solving problem with the method similar to that used in your second sample.